# Conky graphs out of the graph border

Tags: graphics, conky, system-monitor

I'm having a strange issue with Conky. The graphs are moving outside of their borders.

[image: desktop screenshot]

My '.conkyrc' can be found here: http://pastebin.com/nWPVjKJB

Does anyone know how I can fix this problem? I can't seem to find any solution

I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit

Answer (score 1):

I've found out the issue with it. This seems to be some sort of bug, but I noticed that the text seems to have a "drop shadow" now, so I decided to add the 'draw_shades false' option to my .conkyrc and that seemed to have fixed the problem.  I don't know how it did this in the first place, since I never had that option, but it's fixed now.